# React svg getTotalLength

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, css-animations

I want to animate an SVG path using react (https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/ , but in ReactJS). 
To do that correctly, I need to know total length of a path, in JS you can do just path.getTotalLength(), how can I achieve the same when my path is created by JSX?
Thanks

Comment: Add a reference to your path inside the jsx, or after componentDidMount use reactDOM.findDOMNode(ReactComponent for that path)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where React's refs come in handy see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

basically when you are creating the svg you would set a ref on the path and then you can access that ref (which is actually the element in the dom) and call the getTotalLength()

```
<svg><path ref="path"> </svg>
```

and then as long as the function you are  using is a part of your react compnent you can just do

```
var path = this.refs.path;
var pathLength = path.getTotalLength()
```

if you are using es6, string refs are being deprecated and you would actually do something like

```
    <svg><path ref={(ref) => this.path = ref}> </svg>
```

either way works the latter is the preferred way and if you do the latter way you wouldn't call `this.refs.path` but just `this.path` to access the dom node